# i am tryen to implement this code f sql but stil get me an error i really dont know why

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table student (
student_ID number(6) primary key,
student_name varchar (25) unique ,
address varchar ,
sex char, 
manager_ID number(6) REFERENCES maneger (manager_ID) , 
birth_date date NOT NULL 
);
create table Classes (
class_ID number(6) primary key ,
student_ID number (6)REFERENCES student (student_ID), FOREIGN KEY
);
create table manager (
manager_ID number (6) primary key,
manager_name char ,
address varchar,
Teacher_ID number (6) FOREIGN KEY, REFERENCES teacher (Teacher_ID),
sex char
);
create table teacher (
Teacher_ID number (6), primary key,
teacher_name varchar, 
address varchar , 
class_ID number (6)  FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Classes (class_ID) ,
subject_name varchar REFERENCES subject (subject_name)
);
create table subject (
subject_name varchar  primary key,
marks number 
);
create learn (
student_ID number (6) REFERENCES student (student_ID), 
subject_name varchar REFERENCES subject (subject_name) , 
constraint PK_student primary key (student_ID,subject_name)
);
create table teach (
student_ID number (6)REFERENCES student (student_ID) , 
Teacher_ID number (6) REFERENCES teacher (Teacher_ID),
constraint PK_teach primary key (student_ID,Teacher_ID)
);
```

Comment: It helps if you tell us the error. You need to create reference tables before referencing tables and spell manager correctly in student.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- Few syntaxes are not correct
- `int(6)` should be used instead of `number(6)` in mysql
- `varchar` must have data size with it. - `varchar(200)`
- Foreign key must be created after referred table is created

Few example of correct syntax with your sample schema is

```
create table student 
(
    student_ID int(6) primary key,
    student_name varchar (25) unique ,
    address varchar(200) ,
    sex char(10), 
    manager_ID int(6),
    birth_date date NOT NULL 
);

create table Classes 
(
    class_ID int(6) primary key ,
    student_ID int (6) references student (student_ID) 
);
```

[Db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aa1307e89b0711588c2b5dc731f4652c) with correct table definition. Please add foreign key using `alter table table_name add constraint ....`